# MySQL sum up some CASE WHEN functions

Tags: mysql, join, case

Is there a possibility to minimize three CASE-functions into one while I'm expecting three different expressions for any CASE?

So all CASE-calls are dependent on one value (con.category_id).
I hope you can help me to clean up this SQL statement by conserving the whole functionality.

```
SELECT 
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(con.content_date_publishing) AS time, 
 CASE 
  when con.category_id IS NOT NULL 
 THEN 
  con.category_id 
 ELSE 
  0 
 END AS category_id, 
 CASE 
  when con.category_id IS NOT NULL 
 THEN 
  cat.category_name_de 
 ELSE 
  NULL 
 END AS category_name 
FROM 
 v5_content AS con, 
 v5_category AS cat 
WHERE content_id = 2 AND 
 CASE 
  when con.category_id IS NOT NULL 
 THEN 
  con.category_id = cat.category_id 
 ELSE 
  1 

END 
LIMIT 
 1
```

Comment: you can use ifnull function.

Comment: Can you give example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the `LEFT JOIN` operator.

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(con.content_date_publishing) AS time,
    cat.category_id,
    cat.category_name_de
FROM v5_content as con
LEFT JOIN v5 category as cat ON con.category_id = cat.category_id
WHERE
    content_id = 2;
```